# not able to save code folding settings in notepad++

Tags: javascript, notepad++

In Notepad++ code folding can be implemented by:

1. Navigating to Language > Define Your Language..
2. In section "Folding in code 1 style"
3. Enter Open keyword and Close keyword

I may have got this working with #region/#endregion but when I go back to the dialog those keywords aren't displayed

I'm using Notepad++ as my Javascript editor so I need the code to run with code folding symbols without errors.

Is it possible to define code folding with a start symbol of //#region and close symbol of //#endregion?  I've tried to follow the steps I used to configure the first #region/#endregion symbols but I haven't been able to get this to work.